# Is there a way to accept full payment from customers later on when their order is ready to deliver in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to develop a website using woocommerce wherein my customers would place an order to get some graphics designed by me as per their requirmens.

Now what I am trying to achieve is to fetch their requirement and if possible get a fraction of total amount from the customer as advance payment. I should then be able to design the graphic as per their requirement which will take some time suppose 2 to 3 days after which I should give them a link to the designed graphic but they should only be able to download it when they pay the rest of the amount i.e. the full amount.

Is there a plugin to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

there is a good paid solution for this which is the official "Woocommerce Deposits" plugin by the Woocommerce company itself:
https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-deposits/

Meanwhile I'm searching for an alternative solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :) ... I will definitely check it out. A free plugin or solution would be great though :)

Comment: I found this useful article too: 
https://www.kasareviews.com/best-woocommerce-deposits-plugins/

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution:
You can use a plugin to offer your customers to send you a quote for your service. Once you receive the quote you add your product and send them back the quote with real order for them to pay. You first them the % they need to pay for you to start the service, and after you finish and confirm the final work you MANUALLY send another order with a full price this time.

This is a free plugin to do so.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote/

Another cool plugin to help you with manual work:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-invoice-gateway/

TO put this solution simple you just need to send the first deposit payment separately from the final delivery payment. You can do with multiply ways and tools, so it's up to you.

Thanks